# Is it possible to view the first commit in my GitHub-hosted UiPath project after accidentally overwriting it?

Tags: github, uipath

Is there a method available for reviewing the initial commit within my UiPath project hosted on GitHub, even if it has been inadvertently overwritten?

I have tried to to see my commit history but it does not show my initial commit which was a day before.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.